# Trouble Installing/Using Grails Release Plugin 2.2.1

Tags: maven, grails

I'm trying to get the Grails [release plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/release) to work, but running into some trouble.  The current version of Grails that ships with STS/GGTS is 2.2.3, so I can't use the most recent version (3.0) of the release plugin because that requires Grails 2.3. Instead, I tried to install version 2.2.1.

I started by adding the following to my BuildConfig.groovy and refreshed my dependencies.

```
plugins {
... // other plugin dependencies 

    build ':release:2.2.1', ':rest-client-builder:1.0.3', {
        export = false
    }
... // other plugin dependencies 
}
```

but I got the following error when I ran grails maven-install

```
| Script 'MavenInstall' not found, did you mean:
   1) UninstallPlugin
   2) InstallPlugin
   3) InstallDependency
   4) InstallJQuery
   5) InstallTemplates
```

.

.

**LOTS OF TROUBLE SHOOTING DETAILS FOLLOW.

YOU CAN JUST SKIP TO PETER'S ANSWER BELOW**

.

.

Then, I found this [JIRA issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8810), and I listed my plug-ins and release was not install, so I tried

```
grails install-plugin release 2.2.1
```

and refreshed my dependencies and I ended up with a compilation error in GrailsCentralDeployer.  It could not find grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder, so I ran

```
grails install-plugin rest-client-builder 1.0.3
```

and refreshed my dependencies and the error went away.  At this point, I'm not sure if the code I added to BuildConfig.groovy is actually doing anything.

Now, when I run

```
grails maven-install --stacktrace
```

I get the following

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.3
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Error Error executing script MavenInstall: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugins.publish.DistributionManagementInfo (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugins.publish.DistributionManagementInfo
```

If it helps, here are the contents of my BuildConfig.groovy

```
removed - refer to edit 2 below
```

**EDIT 1**
This is my was application.properties file

```
#Grails Metadata file
#Thu Jul 25 07:05:41 EDT 2013
app.grails.version=2.2.3
app.name=swiper-admin
app.version=0.1
plugins.spring-security-cas=1.0.5
plugins.spring-security-core=1.2.7.3
plugins.spring-security-ldap=1.0.6
```

I moved the security plugins from here to BuildConfig.groovy and everything worked fine, so the new file looks like this

```
#Grails Metadata file
#Thu Jul 25 07:05:41 EDT 2013
app.grails.version=2.2.3
app.name=swiper-admin
app.version=0.1
```

and my new BuildConfig.groovy looks like this.

```
removed - refer to edit 2 below
```

I ran `grails clean` and then `grails compile` and the `grails maven-install` and got the same `ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugins.publish.DistributionManagementInfo`

I then ran `grails list-plugins --installed` and this is the output

```
removed - refer to edit 2 below
```

**Edit 2**

@peter-ledbrook, Before, I saw your advice, I have freshly cleaned the project.  I added `grails.project.work.dir = "target"` to my BuildConfig.groovy then ran the following

```
user@computer:~/dev/workspace/swiper-admin$ grails clean
| Application cleaned.
user@computer:~/dev/workspace/swiper-admin$ grails refresh-dependencies
| Dependencies refreshed.
user@computer:~/dev/workspace/swiper-admin$ grails maven-install
| Script 'MavenInstall' not found, did you mean:
   1) UninstallPlugin
   2) InstallPlugin
   3) InstallDependency
   4) InstallJQuery
   5) InstallTemplates
> Please make a selection or enter Q to quit: Q
user@computer:~/dev/workspace/swiper-admin$ grails compile
| Compiling 143 source files

| Compiling 27 source files.
user@computer:~/dev/workspace/swiper-admin$ grails maven-install
| Script 'MavenInstall' not found, did you mean:
   1) UninstallPlugin
   2) InstallPlugin
   3) InstallDependency
   4) InstallJQuery
   5) InstallTemplates
> Please make a selection or enter Q to quit: Q
user@computer:~/dev/workspace/swiper-admin$
```

My BuildConfig.groovy looks like this

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.war.file = "${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.work.dir = "target"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") { }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies { }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.2"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
        build ':release:2.2.1', ':rest-client-builder:1.0.3', { export = false }

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
        compile ":db-reverse-engineer:0.5"

        //security
        compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
        compile ":spring-security-cas:1.0.5"
        compile ":spring-security-ldap:1.0.6"
    }
}

grails.project.repos.atlassian_nexus.url = "https://atlassian.liberty.edu/nexus/content/groups/public"
grails.project.repos.atlassian_nexus.username = "terskine"
grails.project.repos.default = "atlassian_nexus"
```

and `grails list-plugins --installed` look like this

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.3
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
Plug-ins you currently have installed are listed below:
-------------------------------------------------------------
cache               1.0.1            --  Cache Plugin
db-reverse-engineer 0.5              --  Grails Database Reverse Engineering Plugin
hibernate           2.2.3            --  Hibernate for Grails
jquery              1.8.3            --  JQuery for Grails
resources           1.2              --  Resources
spring-security-cas 1.0.5            --  Jasig CAS support for the Spring Security plugin.
spring-security-core1.2.7.3          --  Spring Security Core Plugin
spring-security-ldap1.0.6            --  LDAP authentication support for the Spring Security plugin.
tomcat              2.2.3            --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails
webxml              1.4.1            --  WebXmlConfig
To find more info about plugin type 'grails plugin-info [NAME]'
To install type 'grails install-plugin [NAME] [VERSION]'
For further info visit http://grails.org/Plugins
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit** The problem is the `export = false`. Remove that. I don't understand why it's preventing the installation of the plugin, so it's possibly a bug in Grails. Raise an issue in the [Grails JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/).

**Previous answer**

What you're doing looks fine. I would simply add this line to the beginning of `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.work.dir = "target"
```

Save that and then run

```
grails refresh-dependencies
grails maven-install
```

Any time there seem to be strange class-related errors, simply delete the whole of the `target` directory.

Comment: I added `grails.project.work.dir = "target"` to my BuildConfig.groovy then refreshed dependencies and tried to install again with no luck.  The detailed output, along with my updated BuildConfig.groovy is in **Edit 2** in the original question.

Comment: Finally, 'Maven install complete.' Brilliant!  Thanks for all your help, Peter and @burt-beckwith

Comment: issue raised http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10362 thanks again for all the help

Comment: `grails refresh-dependencies` is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `install-plugin`, it's deprecated and removed entirely in 2.3.

You were correct to use `BuildConfig.groovy` - after saving the change you just need to run `grails compile` or some other commandline script that triggers dependency resolution. This will install any missing plugins and their dependencies, and report any errors.

Note that since you ran `install-plugin` you probably have cruft in `application.properties` - be sure to delete any lines in there that refer to installed plugins. For a plugin you can delete everything except for

```
app.grails.version=2.2.3
```

Your `BuildConfig.groovy` looks a bit weird, more of an application type of file than a plugin. You don't need `grails.servlet.version`, `grails.project.target.level`, `grails.project.source.level`, `grails.project.war.file`. Also I like to keep things simple and move everything to the `target` folder with the `grails.project.work.dir` property.

And do you really need all of those plugin dependencies? They make sense in an application, but not in a plugin unless your plugin really does need them:

```
grails.project.work.dir = "target"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   inherits 'global'
   log 'warn'

   repositories {
      grailsCentral()
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
   }

   plugins {
       build ':release:2.2.1', ':rest-client-builder:1.0.3', { export = false }
   }
}

grails.project.repos.foo.url = "https://server.domain.edu/nexus/content/groups/public"
grails.project.repos.foo.username = "bar"
grails.project.repos.default = "foo"
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.  I think I was unclear.  I am working on an application not a plugin.  It's my first grails app, so I really appreciate the advice.  How would your advice about my BuildConfig.groovy change knowing that I'm working on an app not a plugin.

I'll follow through with your advice about cleaning out my application.properties and trying grails compile, and let you know how that goes.  Thanks again.

Comment: Why are you using the release plugin for an application?

Comment: I am trying to deploy a WAR to a private Nexus repo where our automated deployment tool picks it up to deploy to our various environments

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to get install maven-ant-tasks in compile stage. So I added following code snippet in BuildConfig.groovy

Grails version 2.1.4

```
    dependencies {
        compile "org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3"
   }
```